# Incremental copy by Change Tracking, Using Procedure and Trigger but output being lag for 1 execute time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, change-tracking

I am trying to demo incremental copy from a table in a database A (source) to another table in another database B (destination) with using Change Tracking.

I create two tables with the same name in two different databases (table name: `check_exist_Jan_2024`) and a table named `table_store_ChangeTracking_version` to store the Change Tracking information.

The idea is the `table_store_ChangeTracking_version` stores the last change tracking version. When table in database A has been modified (by insert, delete, or update), the `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()` will increase. I will compare `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()` with the stored "Last Change Tracking Version" in `table_store_ChangeTracking_version` to find ID of rows in source table had been modified then copied these rows to destination table.

After all, I update the `table_store_ChangeTracking_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()`. I using a procedure and trigger to automate this process.

The problem is when I try to at first time I insert values to source table, there are nothing happened in destination table. Then I insert another values to source table, the first row appear in destination table. And so on, when I insert value to source table third time, the second row appear in destination table. Same thing happened with updating change version process in `table_store_ChangeTracking_version`.

Here is my SQL code:

```
-- CREATE PROCEDURE for updating data in table_store_ChangeTracking_version
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_ChangeTracking_Version (@TableName varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Current_ChangeTracking_version BIGINT;
    SET @Current_ChangeTracking_version = (SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() as CurrentChangeTrackingVersion)

    UPDATE table_store_ChangeTracking_version
    SET [SYS_CHANGE_VERSION] = @Current_ChangeTracking_version
    WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
END


-- CREATE PROCEDURE for Incremental copy data from source to another table
ALTER PROCEDURE Incremental_Copy_check_exist_Jan_2024 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Last_ChangeTracking_version BIGINT, @Current_ChangeTracking_version BIGINT;
    SET @Current_ChangeTracking_version = (SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() as CurrentChangeTrackingVersion);
    SET @Last_ChangeTracking_version = (select max(SYS_CHANGE_VERSION) as last_version
                                        from table_store_ChangeTracking_version
                                        where TableName = 'dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024');

    -- Inserted data or updated data
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 ON
    Insert into B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 (LocationID, Name, CostRate, Availability)

    SELECT source_tbl.LocationID, source_tbl.Name, source_tbl.CostRate, source_tbl.Availability
    FROM A.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 AS source_tbl
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN changetable(changes A.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024, @Last_ChangeTracking_version) AS ct
        ON ct.LocationID = source_tbl.LocationID
    WHERE ct.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION <= @Current_ChangeTracking_version 
      AND ct.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION IN ('I', 'U')

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 OFF;

    -- Deleted data
    DELETE FROM B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 
    WHERE LocationID IN (SELECT LocationID
                         FROM changetable(changes A.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024, @Last_ChangeTracking_version) AS ct
                         WHERE ct.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'D');
END;

-- Create trigger when source table has been changed
ALTER TRIGGER Incremental_ChangeTracking_Trigger
ON A.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE Incremental_Copy_check_exist_Jan_2024;

    EXECUTE Update_ChangeTracking_Version
            @TableName = 'dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024';
END
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Change Tracking is not synchronous, it normally runs a bit behind transactions. You need to use the trigger tables `inserted` and `deleted` to merge the changes.

Comment: The trigger code is running in transaction, so the changes won't be visible until the trigger finishes. I suggest perhaps that trigger fires a sql agent job that recalculates the data, if you really need it

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Change Tracking *at all* to do what you want. Change Tracking is asynchronous, so it always runs a little behind committed transactions (and doesn't pick up on uncommitted transactions at all).

Instead, just use normal `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to do this. The easiest is to just write three separate triggers.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER check_exist_Jan_2024_INS
ON dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 ON;

INSERT B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 t
  (LocationID, Name, CostRate, Availability)
SELECT
  i.LocationID,
  i.Name,
  i.CostRate,
  i.Availability
FROM inserted i;
```

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER check_exist_Jan_2024_UPD
ON dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024
AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE t
SET
  Name = i.Name,
  CostRate = i.CostRate,
  Availability = i.Availability
FROM B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 t
JOIN inserted i ON i.LocationID = t.LocationID
WHERE (    -- use NOT EXISTS (SELECT ... INTERSECT SELECT ...) syntax on older versions
     i.Name IS DISTINCT FROM t.Name
  OR i.CostRate IS DISTINCT FROM t.CostRate
  OR i.Availability IS DISTINCT FROM t.Availability
  );
```

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER check_exist_Jan_2024_DEL
ON dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024
AFTER DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE t
FROM B.dbo.check_exist_Jan_2024 t
JOIN deleted d ON d.LocationID = t.LocationID;
```